# OWB (Oracle Warehouse Builder) migration assistant encounter an invalid substitution error

Tags: database, oracle, data-warehouse

Currently, we am using OWB11gR2(11.2.0.4) for the ETL process. We are planning to upgrade our oracle database into database 19c. Since, OWB is no longer exist after 11gR2, we need to migrate OWB into ODI (Oracle Data Integrator). After go through different document, we found an way to migrate owb to odi using owb migration assistant.
We are trying to run the migration assistant in AIX 7.2 in the following way.

```
$OWB_HOME/owb/bin/unix/
./migration.sh <odi_master_password> <odi_user_password> <owb_workspace_owner_password> <configuration_file>
```

However, migration assistant failed with the following error.

> migraiton.sh[24]: "${1:0:13}": 0403-011 the Specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: This is a so-called _bashism_ (i.e. bash-specific extension which is not supported by other shells). The simplest solution is installing and using bash: `bash ./migration.sh ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a workaround to fix the issue.

```
$OWB_HOME/owb/bin/unix/ ~/.bashrc
./migration.sh <odi_master_password> <odi_user_password> <owb_workspace_owner_password> <configuration_file>
```

Or use full path of the bash before the migration assistant script.

```
/usr/bin/bash migration.sh <odi_master_password> <odi_user_password> <owb_workspace_owner_password> <configuration_file>
```